# Twitter = how to embed a specific tweett + comments?

Tags: twitter

I'd like to find out **how to embed a specific tweet + comments**.
I know how to embed the whole timeline (with Twitter widgets):

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/stats_canada" data-widget-id="608870269030137856">Tweets by @stats_canada</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

but I just need **to embed one tweet** using that widget (if possible).
For example this particular one:
https://twitter.com/stats_canada/status/230694020031078400?s=17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed that specific tweet using this code:

```
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">The average Canadian says sorry over 45,000 times a day.</p>&mdash; Stats Canada (@stats_canada) <a href="https://twitter.com/stats_canada/status/230694020031078400">August 1, 2012</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

However, replies are different. The current twitter API doesn't seem to allow for embedding of entire conversations. What you can do after embedding this tweet is getting the embed quote for each reply, and then unchecking the `"Include parent tweet"` for each embed code. You can then add each one below the original tweet.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround, Zavtra.
Not taht it will work but - thanks for confirming it's not possible to get what I am looking for from Twitter in one go. Cheers!